# Charge conjugation of fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, definition, dirac-equation, spinors, charge-conjugation

[This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-symmetry#:%7E:text=Charge%20reversal%20in%20electroweak%20theory,-The%20laws%20of&text=A%20left%2Dhanded%20neutrino%20would,symmetry%20in%20the%20weak%20interaction.) on Wikipedia says, "In the language of quantum field theory, charge conjugation transforms as -

- $\psi \Rightarrow -i\big(\bar{\psi} \gamma ^0 \gamma ^2 \big)^T $
- $\bar{\psi} \Rightarrow -i\big(\gamma ^0 \gamma ^2 \psi \big)^T $

Could someone explain the reason behind choosing this **specific** mathematical transformation for charge conjugation (since the only thing it's supposed to do is invert the sign of all charges to convert a particle into its anti-particle)? Any relevant sources are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement the symmetries as transformations on the fields (and also corresponding operators on the Hilbert-space in the QFT), i.e. transformations of the dynamical variables in your Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}(\psi, \bar{\psi},...)$. The reason is that these symmetries of the Lagrangian have important consequences: Continuous symmetries for example give classically conserved current through Noethers theorem and Ward identities in the quantum theory. Discrete symmetries, like $C,P,T$ are also important.

Now let us apply the charge conjugation, which you defined above, to the QED Lagrangian. One can see that
$\bar{\psi} \partial_{\mu} \gamma^{\mu} \psi$ and $\bar{\psi} \psi$ are invariant, but $\bar{\psi} \gamma^{\mu} \psi \rightarrow - \bar{\psi} \gamma^{\mu} \psi$, so the QED interaction term transforms as
$$
e A_{\mu} \bar{\psi} \gamma^{\mu} \psi \rightarrow - e A_{\mu} \bar{\psi} \gamma^{\mu} \psi,
$$
which is the same as taking $e \rightarrow -e$. This is one easy way of seeing why charge conjugation is an appropriate name. Now if we let $A_{\mu} \rightarrow - A_{\mu}$ under $C$ we get a symmetry of the QED Lagrangian and a consequence is for example Furry's theorem.

I also strongly recommend you to read p.192-195 in Schwartz's QFT book, where the explanation is more detailed and there is a more correct justification of the name charge conjugation.

Answer (score 0):

The charge conjugation symmetry is the proper time reversal symmetry.

It becomes an exact symmetry of relativistic quantum systems if we combine with space-time time reversal and parity, due to unitarity.

About the techinical details you are raising I think that this transformation looks complicated just in you notation, afterwards you are hiding the indices.

I think that in four dimensions there is a suitable choice of indices ($SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ indices) where the charge conjugation reduces to:

$$\psi^{\alpha}\leftrightarrow \overline\psi^{\dot\alpha}\,\quad \alpha=1,2\;\quad \dot\alpha=3,4\,.$$